Why does hibernate envers throw PersistenceException?
I am using hibernate envers for fields changes auditing. hibernate envers throws PersistenceException from time to time. Only k8s pod restarting helps with it. So the bug is regular, but happens not often (several times in a month).
Response body:

"status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "PersistenceException",
    "path": "/api/bookinglegs/47449a96-a63f-40d0-9111-9d84eb1530ef/history",
    "code": "internal_server_error"

Logs:
2024-09-15T12:35:38.808Z  INFO 1 --- [io-8080-exec-14] d.m.s.c.e.h.CommonGlobalExceptionHandler : Request Failed: ErrorResponseDto{status=500, error='Internal Server Error', message='PersistenceException', path='/api/bookinglegs/d47804d2-a929-4242-88ce-0c46417d6e84/history', code='internal_server_error'}
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:741)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
io.sentry.spring.jakarta.SentrySpringFilter.doFilterInternal(SentrySpringFilter.java:71)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
io.sentry.spring.jakarta.tracing.SentryTracingFilter.doFilterInternal(SentryTracingFilter.java:87)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
de.mopla.server.security.filter.FirebaseSecurityFilter.doFilterInternal(FirebaseSecurityFilter.java:143)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
io.sentry.spring.jakarta.SentryUserFilter.doFilterInternal(SentryUserFilter.java:56)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
de.mopla.server.security.filter.ResponseAddAllowMethodsHeaderFilter.doFilter(ResponseAddAllowMethodsHeaderFilter.java:30)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:895)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1003)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor478.invoke(Unknown Source)
de.mopla.server.core.restcontroller.HistoryRestController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getBookingLegHistory(<generated>)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java:199)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor478.invoke(Unknown Source)
de.mopla.server.core.restcontroller.HistoryRestController.getBookingLegHistory(HistoryRestController.java:26)
de.mopla.server.core.services.HistoryService.getHistoryForEntity(HistoryService.java:43)
org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.getResultList(AbstractAuditQuery.java:115)
org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.RevisionsOfEntityQuery.list(RevisionsOfEntityQuery.java:179)
org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.RevisionsOfEntityQuery.getQueryResults(RevisionsOfEntityQuery.java:211)
org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.buildAndExecuteQuery(AbstractAuditQuery.java:109)
org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.list(QuerySqmImpl.java:1032)
org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:374)
org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:165)
2024-09-15T12:35:38.808Z ERROR 1 --- [io-8080-exec-14] d.m.s.c.e.h.CommonGlobalExceptionHandler : PersistenceException with message 'Converting `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException` to JPA `PersistenceException` : could not prepare statement' and stack trace: 
2024-09-15T12:35:38.807Z  INFO 1 --- [io-8080-exec-14] d.m.s.c.e.h.CommonGlobalExceptionHandler : No separate exception handler for class jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException, return the default response
2024-09-15T12:35:38.805Z ERROR 1 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Connection is closed
2024-09-15T12:35:38.805Z  WARN 1 --- [io-8080-exec-14] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null

k8s pod restarting helps
code:
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class HistoryRestController {

    @Autowired
    private HistoryService historyService;

    @GetMapping("/api/bookinglegs/{uuid}/history")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('PRIV_CAN_READ_HISTORY')")
    public List<HistoryDto> getBookingLegHistory(@PathVariable UUID uuid) {
        return historyService.getHistoryForEntity(BookingLegEntity.class, uuid);
    }
}


@Slf4j
@Service
public class HistoryService {
    @Autowired
    private AuditReader auditReader;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @NotNull
    public <T> List<HistoryDto> getHistoryForEntity(Class<T> entityClass, UUID uuid) {
        List<Object[]> auditDataBookingLeg = auditReader.createQuery()
            .forRevisionsOfEntityWithChanges(entityClass, true)
            .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(uuid))
            .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("timestamp").asc())
            .getResultList();
        // mapping the result to HistoryDto
        // ... 
}
}

@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED, withModifiedFlag = true)
@Getter
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraphs({
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = "bookingLegEntityWithPassengers", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("passengerList"))
})
@Table(name = "BOOKING_LEGS",
    indexes = {
        @Index(name = "idx_distributor", columnList = "distributor")
    })
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE BOOKING_LEGS SET deleted = true WHERE id=?")
@Where(clause = "deleted=false or deleted is null")
public class BookingLegEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;

    // it is important to not use CascadeType.Merge here: if we store booking-legs after scheduling,
    // we do not want to change anything related to the booking-entity (e.g. payment states that have been changed by
    // the user while scheduling was happening)
    // it is important to not use CascadeType.All: deletion should not be cascaded
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BELONGS_TO")
    private BookingEntity belongsTo;

    // stores the sequence info within a booking with multiple legs
    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "SORTING")
    private int sorting;

    @NotAudited
    @Type(JsonBinaryType.class)
    @Column(name = "FROM_LOCATION", columnDefinition = "JSONB")
    private Location from;

    @NotAudited
    @Type(JsonBinaryType.class)
    @Column(name = "TO_LOCATION", columnDefinition = "JSONB")
    private Location to;

    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "ORIGINAL_START_TIMEWINDOW_START")
    private Instant originalStartTimewindowStart;

    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "ORIGINAL_START_TIMEWINDOW_END")
    private Instant originalStartTimewindowEnd;

    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "ORIGINAL_END_TIMEWINDOW_START")
    private Instant originalEndTimewindowStart;

    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "ORIGINAL_END_TIMEWINDOW_END")
    private Instant originalEndTimewindowEnd;

    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "START_TIMEWINDOW_START")
    @Convert(converter = InstantTimestampConverter.class)
    private Instant startTimewindowStart;

    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "START_TIMEWINDOW_END")
    @Convert(converter = InstantTimestampConverter.class)
    private Instant startTimewindowEnd;

    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "END_TIMEWINDOW_START")
    @Convert(converter = InstantTimestampConverter.class)
    private Instant endTimewindowStart;

    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "END_TIMEWINDOW_END")
    @Convert(converter = InstantTimestampConverter.class)
    private Instant endTimewindowEnd;

    @NotAudited
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DISTRIBUTOR")
    private DistributorEntity distributor;

    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "TRANSPORT_TYPE")
    @Convert(converter = TripTypeEnumConverter.class)
    private TripTypeEnum transportType;

    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "ROUTE_NAME")
    private String routeName; // "route" in gtfs file

    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "TRIP_NAME")
    private String tripName; // "shortTripName" in gtfs file

    @Getter
    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "AGENCY_NAME")
    private String agencyName; // "agencyName" in gtfs file

    @Getter
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    // do not cascade here, we save booking-legs and scheduled-legs separately after scheduling (easier to handle since they are connected with each other)
    @JoinColumn(name = "GET_ON")
    private ScheduledLegEntity getOn;

    @Getter
    @NotAudited
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    // do not cascade here, we save booking-legs and scheduled-legs separately after scheduling (easier to handle since they are connected with each other)
    @JoinColumn(name = "GET_OFF")
    private ScheduledLegEntity getOff;

    /**
     * -- GETTER --
     * The scheduling state of this booking-leg.
     * <p>
     * <ul>
     *     <li><b>NEW:</b> this booking-leg has not been scheduled yet</li>
     *     <li><b>SCHEDULED_AUTOMATICALLY:</b> this booking-leg was scheduled automatically</li>
     *     <li><b>SCHEDULED_MANUALLY:</b> this booking-leg was scheduled/assigned manually</li>
     *     <li><b>FAILED_TO_SCHEDULE:</b> the last try to schedule this booking-leg has failed.</li>
     * </ul>
     */
    @Column(name = "SCHEDULING_STATE")
    @Convert(converter = SchedulingStateEnumConverter.class)
    private SchedulingStateEnum schedulingState = SchedulingStateEnum.NEW;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CREATED_BY")
    private RecurringManualBookingLegEntity createdBy;

    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    @Convert(converter = TitleNullableConverter.class)
    private Title title;

    @Column(name = "DRIVER_NOTICE")
    @Convert(converter = DriverNoticeNullableConverter.class)
    private DriverNotice driverNotice;

    @Column(name = "BOOKING_NOTICE")
    @Convert(converter = BookingNoticeNullableConverter.class)
    private BookingNotice bookingNotice;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MANUALLY_ASSIGNED_TO")
    private AssignmentEntity manuallyAssignedTo;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "CHECK_IN_STATE")
    private CheckInStateEnum checkInState = CheckInStateEnum.NEW;

    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "SCHEDULER_KEY")
    @Convert(converter = ObjectConverter.class)
    private SchedulerKey schedulerKey;

    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_AMOUNT")
    private Integer paymentAmount;

    @Setter
    @Column(name = "CANCELLATION_FEE_AMOUNT")
    private Integer cancellationFeeAmount;

    @Setter
    @Column(name = "CANCELLATION_FEE_REASON")
    @Convert(converter = CancellationFeeReasonEnumConverter.class)
    private CancellationFeeReasonEnum cancellationFeeReason = CancellationFeeReasonEnum.NOT_CANCELLED;

    /**
     * Once the scheduling has decided on a time for the trip, we check if this changes the price of the trip.
     * The trip can only become cheaper. If a cheaper price is decided, it is stored as an overwritten payment amount.
     */
    @Column(name = "OVERWRITTEN_PAYMENT_AMOUNT")
    private Integer overwrittenPaymentAmount;

    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_CURRENCY_CODE")
    @Convert(converter = CurrencyCodeConverter.class)
    private CurrencyCodeEnum currencyCode;

    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_FORM")
    @Convert(converter = PaymentFormConverter.class)
    private PaymentFormEnum paymentForm;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_STATE")
    private PaymentStateEnum paymentState = PaymentStateEnum.TO_PAY;

    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "INVOICE_ID")
    @Convert(converter = StripeInvoiceIdConverter.class)
    private StripeInvoiceId invoiceId;

    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_ID")
    @Convert(converter = StripePaymentIdConverter.class)
    private StripePaymentId paymentId;

    @Type(JsonBinaryType.class)
    @Column(name = "START_TRIP_LOCATION", columnDefinition = "JSONB")
    private Location startTripLocation;

    @Type(JsonBinaryType.class)
    @Column(name = "END_TRIP_LOCATION", columnDefinition = "JSONB")
    private Location endTripLocation;

    // TODO: MC-5293, should be replaced as cancellationLocation
    @Deprecated(forRemoval = true)
    @Type(JsonBinaryType.class)
    @Column(name = "NO_SHOW_LOCATION", columnDefinition = "JSONB")
    private Location noShowLocation;

    @Type(JsonBinaryType.class)
    @Column(name = "CANCELLATION_LOCATION", columnDefinition = "JSONB")
    private Location cancellationLocation;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "CREATED_TIME")
    @Audited(withModifiedFlag = true, modifiedColumnName = "created_time_mod")
    private Timestamp creationTimestamp;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "UPDATED_TIME")
    private Timestamp updateTimestamp;

    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "DELETED")
    private boolean deleted;

    @NotAudited
    @Type(JsonBinaryType.class)
    @Column(name = "METADATA", columnDefinition = "JSONB DEFAULT '{}'", nullable = false)
    private Map<String, Object> metadata = new HashMap<>();

    @NotAudited
    @OneToOne
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RESERVATION_ID")
    private PrivateTripReservationEntity reservation;

    /**
     * The zone this booking leg was originally created in
     * Prefer using this zone for calculating pricing if multiple zones are available
     */
    @NotAudited
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PREFERRED_ZONE_ID")
    private ZoneEntity preferredZone;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bookingLeg", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<PassengerEntity> passengerList = new HashSet<>();

    @NotAudited
    @Column(name = "SPECIAL_NEEDS")
    @Convert(converter = SpecialNeedsConverter.class)
    private SpecialNeedsEnum specialNeeds;

exception happens in
    .getResultList();


A very tough guess, the error says "connection is closed" , so you cannot communicate with the persistent object. Once or twice a month seems like that old problem of application container "refresh" that restarts the application, I do not know an SQL servers policy on periodic refresh of sever environment and it's persistent tables.

Could be a connection pool configuration issue where broken connections are not evicted. It's a guessing game with nothing more than "it happens" to go on.
